# Sequence of closed sets (Milnor's proof)

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

I've got a question about a descending sequence of closed sets.
Milnor writes in his book "FROM THE DIFFERENTIABLE VIEWPOINT".
In his proof of Sards Theorem he wrote:
Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ be a smooth map, with $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $C_i$ denote the set of $x$ such that all partial derivatives of $f$ of order $\le i$ vanish at $x$. Thus we have a descending sequence of closed sets $C\supset C_1 \supset C_2...$.
But I don't see why for example $C_1$ is closed in $C$ or more generally why $C_i$ is closed in $C_{i-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is smooth, then all the partials are continuous. Now we have a general fact about topology:

> If $G: A\rightarrow B$ is a continuous function, then $\{x: G(x)=y\}$ is closed, for every $y\in B$.

(OK, fine, this isn't strictly true: I need $B$ to have the (very basic) property that *points are closed*. But $\mathbb{R}^p$ certainly has this property.)

Now, each $C_i$ is an intersection of sets of the form "so-and-so partial is zero", and hence (by the above, and since each of the partials is continuous) an intersection of closed sets; and the intersection of closed sets is closed. So each $C_i$ is closed.

Comment: Ok! But, is $C_i$ only closed in $C_{i-1}$ or is $C_i$ closed in U?

Comment: @Laura Each $C_i$ is closed - that is, closed in $U$. In addition, each $C_i$ is closed in $C_{i-1}$, since each $C_i$ is a subset of $C_{i-1}$. Exercise: If $A$ is closed in $B$, and $B$ is closed in $C$, then $A$ is closed in $C$.

Comment: Actually, the better exercise is: if $A\subseteq B$, and $B$ is closed in $C$, then $A$ is closed in $C$ if and only if $A$ is closed in $B$.